# How to import multiple csv in one dataframe with different column names and unimportant columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, import

Let's take sample data. Imagine I have two csv documents in one directory. When I import them separately, I get these two dataframes :

```
# first one
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     1   2.0   2.0
1     2   4.8   4.8
2     3   1.0   1.0

# second one
   ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD
0     5   9.0   2.9   2.2
1     1   7.8   2.2   9.8
2     2   2.0   7.0   1.6
```

I would like to import them in a unique dataframe, knowing that I have the following dictionary :

```
Dict_col_names = {
    "Col1" : "ColA",
    "Col2" : "ColB",
    "Col3" : "ColC"
}
```

So I can have through this dictionary the correspondence between column names. If a column name is not in the dictionary, I don't want to import it.
I know that the basic code to import csv of an entire directory into a single dataframe is the following :

```
import glob
import os
path_train = r'C:\Users\XXX'
all_files_train = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_train, "*.csv"))
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f,sep=",") for f in all_files_train),sort=False)
```

But I can't find a way to modify it in order to meet what I would like to do (knowing that in reality, I have a lot of csv of both types). Could you please help me ?

Expected output :

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     1   2.0   2.0
1     2   4.8   4.8
2     3   1.0   1.0
3     5   9.0   2.9
4     1   7.8   2.2
5     2   2.0   7.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `rename`

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f,sep=",").rename(columns = Dict_col_names) for f in all_files_train),sort=False)
```

If two data frame contain diff columns we can add `join ='inner'`

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f,sep=",").rename(columns = Dict_col_names) for f in all_files_train),sort=False , join='inner')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for the correspondances between the columns but I still import the data of ColD, which is not in the dictionary. I could drop the columns which are not in the dictionary after the import, but do you know if there is a direct method, during the import ?

Comment: @Ewdlam i am not sure , so you mean you want to drop the column before reading it ? If so , this will need you know the position of the unwanted column ~

Comment: I am sure you have the good idea with inner but you current line of code gives me an empty dataframe, with just index. And I rather say that I don't want to import the ColD data, not really drop it, but anyway, the result is the most important